# Ubuntu v18.04 in Hyper-V VM unable to get network address when using default network switch

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I'm using the default NetworkManager in Ubuntu and the VM logs show that it is sending DHCPDISCOVER messages (if I am reading this correctly). 
I need to use the default switch so that the VM traffic is NATed.

This is the first time that I've used Hyper-V what do I need to check for?

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709.

I downloaded a Window dev VM from Microsoft and that VM couldn't get an IP address either so it is not an Ubuntu guest OS issue.

Comment: BTW, I ended up being able to switch back to VirtualBox and having VM networking within the Windows VPN.